# Nativescript TabView Loads only Once

Tags: javascript, tabs, nativescript, tabview

I'm trying to build an Android & iOS app using Nativescript core (Javascript). Here in app-root.xml I've a tabview in which I've 3 tabs. Each of the tabs data are related with one another. Example in first tab I show a list of products with 'Favourite' option for each items, if I favourite a product it should show in the second tab. But in my app since the Tabs are loaded while the app is opened the changes are not reflecting when the tabs are selected. But If I close and open the application the changes are shown in the Tabs. Please tell me How I could re-load the tab each and every time when it is selected.

Thanks in advance. Apologies for my poor language.

Answer (score 0):

Generally with web apps you will have a single container and a tab like view above / below container, tapping on specific tab will load correspondent tab item within the container.

But with mobile apps the TabView component loads all tabs on its own container, so it won't have to reload tab when you switch between tabs. That's totally the expected behaviour.

You may use services / BehaviorSubject etc., to hold the dependent data, so when you change it form one tab, the other tab gets updated too.